# How to use specific GPU's in keras for multi-GPU training?

Tags: keras, multi-gpu

I have a server with 4 GPU's. I want to use exactly 2 of them for multi-GPU training.

Keras documentation provided  [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-run-a-keras-model-on-multiple-gpus)  gives some insight about how to use multiple GPU's but I want to select the specific GPU's. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
c = []
for d in ['/device:GPU:2', '/device:GPU:3']:
    with K.tf.device(d):
        config = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=4,\
        inter_op_parallelism_threads=4, allow_soft_placement=True,\
        device_count = {'CPU' : 1, 'GPU' : 2})
        a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3])
        b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2])
        c.append(tf.matmul(a, b))
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    sum = tf.add_n(c)
session = tf.Session(config=config)
K.set_session(session)
```

I think this should work . You should be having the number(index) of GPU devices you want to use. In this case its 2 and 3.  Relevant links 1)https://github.com/carla-simulator/carla/issues/116
2) https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu#using_multiple_gpus

Comment: what is c in the line 'sum = tf.add_n(c)' ?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Let me try this.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to compile the Keras model with a `tf.distribute` [Strategy](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distribute_strategy) by creating and compiling your model in the strategy's scope. For example:

```
import contextlib

def model_scope(devices):
    if 1 < len(devices):
        strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices)
        scope = strategy.scope()
    else:
        scope = contextlib.supress() # Python 3.4 up
    return scope

devices = ['/device:GPU:2', '/device:GPU:3']

with model_scope(devices):
    # create and compile your model
    model = get_model()
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss)
```